# Deleting file using CSOM - C# deletes file but throws exception "File Not Found"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

i am working on function that deletes a file from Share Point Documents. The function works but it throws exception that file not found.

```
protected void DeleteFile(string filename, Uri hostWeb)
    {
        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/" + filename);
            f.DeleteObject();
            clientContext.Load(f);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Delete file here but throw Exception                
            Console.Write("deleted");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try reversing the order of DeleteObject and Load so you get:

```
protected void DeleteFile(string filename, Uri hostWeb)
    {
        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/" + filename);
            clientContext.Load(f);
            f.DeleteObject();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Delete file here but throw Exception                
            Console.Write("deleted");
        }
    }
```